# How can I merge a different data frame with the one I created for cluster analysis in R?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Here's my issue: from a larger data frame, I created a subset data frame that only included the variables I needed for cluster analysis. See below for example using iris data. **Suppose I want to calculate the average Petal.Width for each cluster group. How can I do this if I didn't include this variable in the cluster analysis df so it wouldn't affect the analysis itself?** I assume I could simply merge two dfs, but (1) I don't have an ID variable to use in this example and (2) even if I had an ID variable, it wouldn't have been included in the cluster analysis df because it would have affected my clusters.

```
data(iris)
clust<-cbind(iris$Sepal.Length, 
             iris$Sepal.Width,
             iris$Petal.Length)
colnames(clust)<-c("sl","sw","pl")
#Skipped some steps I took in between to omit NA values, scale using z-score, and determine optimum number of clusters
fit<-kmeans(clust,3)
aggregate(clust,by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)
clustdf<-data.frame(clust,fit$cluster)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just run kmeans on your subset of columns without splitting the original df.  Then you don't have to worry about merging back your Petal.Width column.

```
   data(iris)
   fit <- kmeans(iris[,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length")],3)
   aggregate(iris[,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")],
    by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)
   clustdf <- data.frame(iris,fit$cluster)
```